# Dynamic URL rewriting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a e-commerce website and I am trying to make its URL better.  I enabled Apache configuration, then created a .htaccess file, but my URL is still the same.  I am not able to figure out where am I going wrong.

If my URL is like this: http://www.public_html/products.php?scatid=72

and I want it to look like this: http://www.public_html.com/products/scatid/72

I have my PHP file as:

```
if($cntrec_prod > 0){
    $cnt = 0;
    mysql_data_seek($srsprod_mst,0);        
    while($srowsprod_mst=mysql_fetch_assoc($srsprod_mst)){
        $db_catone_id    = $srowsprod_mst['prodcatm_id'];
        $db_catone_name    = $srowsprod_mst['prodcatm_name'];
        $db_cattwo_id    = $srowsprod_mst['prodscatm_id'];
        $db_cattwo_name    = $srowsprod_mst['prodscatm_name'];    
        $db_dys_lft        = $srowsprod_mst['dyslft'];            
        $smlimg_lst     = $srowsprod_mst['prodimgd_simg'];
        $avl_prd        = $srowsprod_mst['avlprd'];    
        //$lnkname  = "products.php?scatid=$db_cattwo_id";        
        $ary_imgnm = explode('--',$smlimg_lst);
        $img_cnts = '';
        $img_frstcnts ='';
        $imginc = 0;
        $scatid_lst .= "--".$db_cattwo_id.'-'.$db_dys_lft;
        for($inc=0;$inc<count($ary_imgnm);$inc++){                    
            $scat_imgnm     = $ary_imgnm[$inc];
            $scat_imgpth     = $u_sml_upldpth.$scat_imgnm;                
            if(($scat_imgnm != '') && file_exists($scat_imgpth)){
                $imginc ++;
                if($inc == 0){
                    $img_frstcnts = "<a href='products.php?scatid=$db_cattwo_id' class='catImg'><img src='$scat_imgpth' width='300' height='350' border='0' alt=''></a>";
                }
                $img_cnts = "<a href='products.php?scatid=$db_cattwo_id'><img src='$scat_imgpth' width='300' height='350' /></a>";                    
            }
            else{
                $img_frstcnts = "<a href='products.php?scatid=$db_cattwo_id' class='catImg'><img src='images/noimage.jpg' width='300' height='350' border='0' alt=''></a>";
            }
        }                    
        $dsp_name = $db_cattwo_name;            
?>
```

My .htaccess files contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /public_html/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule products/scatid/(.*)/ products.php?scatid=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule products/scatid/(.*) products.php?scatid=$1 [L,QSA]`
```

Comment: `\$` is wrong you are escaping the `$` symbol instead do `/?$`

Comment: .htaccess for everything isn't the best way. Consider using a **router** or program it urself.

Comment: Tried the change u asked for still the url tends to be same. Thanks for the suggestion @Rahil ny other suggestion would also be hlpful

Comment: can u please tell me or elaborate a bit more for using router @Xatenev

Comment: i am confused if my php echo function used is correct or not ?

Comment: @Priyanka Just tell me `sub-products` is directory or file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the last instance of this cond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

This cond prevents you from getting to the rewrite rule, since the cond could not be fulfilled if the URL is not rewritten.
You also need to change the last rewrite rule as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^sub-products/([0-9]+)$ sub-products?catid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You are right! It's because of the RewriteCond... I edited the answer to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
#add these
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.nl/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Do i need to change the href tag in the php file too?? @Ajay